# jqGrid shows no data from the restful services

Tags: jquery, rest, jqgrid

My jqGrid function brings no data, which comes from Restful Web Services. First below url shows json data successfully in web browser.

http://localhost:8080/RESTfulTestWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres

```
{"user":[
           {"id":"aupres","passwd":"aaa","age":45,"name":"father"},
           {"id":"hwa5383","passwd":"bbb","age":40,"name":"mother"},
           {"id":"julian","passwd":"ccc","age":15,"name":"son"}

]}
```

But my bugs-full jqGrid brings nothing. These are my codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="EUC-KR">
<title>jQuery Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cl").click(function(){

        $Grid = $("#grid");
        $Grid.jqGrid({
            mtype: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/JQueryJsonWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres",
            restful : true,
            contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonReader : {
                root : "user",
                id : "id"
            },
            colNames : [
                'id',
                'passwd',
                'age',
                'name'
            ],
            colModel : [
                { name : 'id',        width:40,  align:'center'},
                { name : 'passwd',    width:80,  align:'left'  },
                { name : 'age',       width:80,  align:'left'  },
                { name : 'name',      width:80,  align:'right' }
            ],
            pager : '#pager',
            rowNum : '10',
            multiselect : true,
            postData : {
                   id : 'id',
                   passwd : 'passwd',
                   age : 'age',
                   name : 'name'
              },
        });  
    })
});
</script>
<button id="cl">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually I have no idea how to contain the json response in Grid.jqGrid function. Where is json responses contained in Grid.jqGrid?

Comment: First of all `dataType: "json"` need be replaced to `datatype: "json"`. `restful: true` is not exist. `contentType` not exist too. The usage of `http://localhost:8080/` prefix could be origin of the problem. One can make standard Ajax requests only inside of the same web site. So the URL should be like `url: "/JQueryJsonWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres"` for example. If you *really need* to access another site, then the site have to allow this. Two main ways are: including JSONP support or including CORS support on the server side.

Comment: One should change the Ajax option corresponds to server protocol: `datatype: "jsonp"`, `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}` or to use `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }}`