# jqGrid call restful service successfully but failed to show the jqGrid ui

Tags: json, rest, jqgrid

This is the RESTful data format

```
{"user":[
           {"id":"aupres","passwd":"aaa","age":45,"name":"father"},
           {"id":"hwa5383","passwd":"bbb","age":40,"name":"mother"},
           {"id":"julian","passwd":"ccc","age":15,"name":"son"}

]}
```

My jqGrid client call the above data successfully. The below image shows the result:

[image]

But this code fails to display the response to the jqGrid. This is my client code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="EUC-KR">
    <title>jqGrid Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $Grid = $("#grid");
       $Grid.jqGrid({

          mtype: "get",
          url: "/JQueryJsonWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres",
          contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",

          jsonReader : {
             root : "user"
          },
          colNames : [
             'id',
             'passwd',
             'age',
             'name'
          ],
          colModel : [
             { name : 'id',        width:40,  align:'center'},
             { name : 'passwd',    width:80,  align:'left'  },
             { name : 'age',       width:80,  align:'left'  },
             { name : 'name',      width:80,  align:'right' }
          ],
          pager : '#pager',
          rowNum : '10',

          loadComplete : onloadComplete,
          loadError : onloadError,
          gridComplete : ongridComplete
       });  

       function onloadComplete(jsonData, status) {
          console.log(jsonData) **// This method shows the above image.**
       }

       function onloadError(status) {
          console.log(status)
       }

       function ongridComplete() {
          console.log("fiished!!!");
       }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836356/jqgrid-shows-no-data-from-the-restful-services#comment57416614_34836356) to your previous question:

- JavaScript is case sensitive language. There are **NO** `dataType: "json"` parameters and the default `datatype: "xml"` will be used.
- Non-existing parameters `contentType` will be ignored too. The returned are wrong if one interpret there as XML data.
- The output which you included come from `onloadError` and not from `onloadComplete`. The parameters of `onloadError` are `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, `errorThrown`. You included the console output of the [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935).
- You should declare variables in JavaScript : use `var $Grid = $("#grid");` instead of `$Grid = $("#grid");`. Including `"use strict"` directive at the beginning on top functions helps to detect such errors (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp)). In the same way I'd recommend you include semicolon after every statement (see `console.log(status)` and `console.log(jsonData)`).
- You should include in all your question which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - my fork, commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The possibilities of the forks will be more and more different. Thus it's important which one you use (or can use).